# Excel line graph based on peak hours of room utilization in a 24 hour day

Tags: excel

I would like to create a line graph that charts  the number of people an office at any give time based on data that shows the time in and time out of groups of people. These groups of people and there time overlap .

Colum1.....Colum2.......Colum3............Colum4.

Team.........TimeIn.......TimeOut...........NumberOfPeople

1.................8 am.........10am................3

2.................8 am..........11am................4

Chart should reflect 7 people in between the hours of 8 and 9 and 4 people in between the hours of 10 and 11.  Thus a line should go up to 7 and flatten out like a step for 1 hour then step down to 4 for the secound hour.

Comment: Actually it could be a bit tricky because you would need two counts for 8am, 0 then 7, same with 11am, 4 then 0. I'm assuming you only want to plot it at intervals of 1 hour? Will have a think about how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have generated two slightly different times for each hour using the following formula

```
=IF((INT(ROW()/2)-1)/24>(MAX(Data!C$2:C$10)-MIN(Data!B$2:B$10)),"",(MIN(Data!B$2:B$10)+(INT(ROW()/2)-1-ISEVEN(ROW())/60)/24))
```

Where your data is in columns A-D of the Data sheet.

Then the number of people at each time is given by

```
=SUMIFS(Data!D$2:D$10,Data!B$2:B$10,"<="&A2,Data!C$2:C$10,">"&A2)
```

[image]

I used a standard scatterplot with straight lines, but had to fix the horizontal scale manually to make it choose a sensible range.

Comment: Thanks that was a similar answer to the results that I eventually came up with. I had to set up columns to represent each hour and in each column mark the number of people present if it was greater than eq to the  the time in  and less than eq to the time out. From there created a pivot table that showed each hour as a separate bar based on the number of people.